# Нужна помощь с Телеграм-ботом

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

При нажатии на кнопку "Получение развернутой информации о враче – ФИО, опыт работы, стоимость приема" Выводит расписание и информацию вместе.Помогите решить проблему.Заранее спасибо!

```
public void RunLogic(
        ITelegramBotClient telegramBotClient,
        ChatState chatState,
        string userInput = "")
    {
      var expectedResponses = _previousState.ExpectedReponsesIfButton();

      if (expectedResponses.Any())
      {
        if (!expectedResponses.Contains(userInput))
        {
          var message = "Я вас не понял!";
          _previousState.RunLogic(telegramBotClient, chatState);
        }
        else
        {
          if (_previousState is DefaultChatState)
          {
            if (userInput == "Просмотр списка врачей и их расписания на текущий месяц")
            {
              chatState.SetChatState(new DoctorList_ShowDoctorsState());
              chatState.ExecuteStateLogic(telegramBotClient);
            }
          }
          else if (_previousState is DoctorList_ShowDoctorsState)
          {
            var map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            map["Оспанова Гульмира Муратовна"] = "Оспанова Гульмира Муратовна (врач-окулист) \n " +
    "Расписание : 11.01.2020 ПН 12:00-13:00 \n " +
    "Расписание : 12.01.2020 ВТ 12:00-13:00";
            map["Лещенко Лев Михайлович"] = "Лещенко Лев Михайлович (врач-окулист) \n " +
    "Расписание : 11.01.2020 ПН 12:00-13:00 \n " +
    "Расписание : 12.01.2020 ВТ 12:00-13:00";
            map["Пак Николай Демидович"] = "Пак Николай Демидович (врач-окулист) \n " +
    "Расписание : 11.01.2020 ПН 12:00-13:00 \n " +
    "Расписание : 12.01.2020 ВТ 12:00-13:00";


            var doctorToSelect = map[userInput];
            chatState.SetChatState(new DoctorList_ShowDoctorScheduleState(doctorToSelect));
            chatState.ExecuteStateLogic(telegramBotClient);
          }
        }
      }
      if (!expectedResponses.Contains(userInput))
      {
        var message = "Я вас не понял!";
        _previousState.RunLogic(telegramBotClient, chatState);

      }

      else if (_previousState is DefaultChatState)
      {
        if (userInput == "Получение развернутой информации о враче – ФИО, опыт работы, стоимость приема")
        {
          chatState.SetChatState(new DoctorList_ShowDoctorsState());
          chatState.ExecuteStateLogic(telegramBotClient);
        }
      }
      else if (_previousState is DoctorList_ShowDoctorsState)
      {
        var map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        map["Оспанова Гульмира Муратовна"] = "Оспанова Гульмира Муратовна (врач-окулист) \n " +
"2012-2018 –г. Алматы, клиника «One Clinic \n " +
"2018-2020–г. Алматы, клиника «EyeDoctor» \n" + "Стоимость приема – 5000 T";
        map["Лещенко Лев Михайлович"] = "Лещенко Лев Михайлович (врач-окулист) \n " +
"2012-2018 –г. Алматы, клиника «One Clinic \n " +
"2018-2020–г. Алматы, клиника «EyeDoctor» \n" + "Стоимость приема – 5000 T";
        map["Пак Николай Демидович"] = "Пак Николай Демидович (врач-окулист) \n " +
"2012-2018 –г. Алматы, клиника «One Clinic \n " +
"2018-2020–г. Алматы, клиника «EyeDoctor» \n" + "Стоимость приема – 5000 T";

        var doctorToSelect = map[userInput];
        chatState.SetChatState(new DoctorList_ShowDoctorInfoState(doctorToSelect));
        chatState.ExecuteStateLogic(telegramBotClient);
      }
    }
```

Comment: перефразируй, слишком все сумбурно. Что нужно получить, что получаешь. В примерах.

Comment: @Andrew, Смотрите при нажатии на кнопку: Получение развернутой информации о враче – ФИО, опыт работы, стоимость приема. Мне нужно получить строки которые описаны в map-е. Я же получаю сначала расписание врача(хотя так не должно быть) и только потом уже всю информацию о докторе